# how to convert mp4 to mp3 in java

Tags: java, file-io, mp3, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm looking for a minimal way to convert mp4 file to mp3 file programmatically from Java. Ideally I also need an cutting of target file.
Do Java libs support this or only 3th party ones? Like jmf, ffmpeg?

Thanks!

Comment: There are already many question about media converting in Java. Very less of them are answered.

Comment: mp4 is a video format (MPEG-4). How can it change to an audio format? Or you want to keep the audio stream and discard the video portion?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of format details, but earlier I used to convert mp4 to mp3 with "format factory" prog, now I'm looking a way to do it programmatically from java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most simple way is to use ffmpeg via a ProcessBuilder using this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -s 00:00:10 -acodec libmp3lame output.mp3
```

This translates to: read mp4 file, ignore video, output 10 seconds in mp3 format

Comment: Is this OS independent?

Comment: @paul hey, does ffmpeg work with non rooted devices. I am trying to use https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java in my android application . Normal commands are working but when i am trying to convert a video to audio it's not working . Help appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know you can use ffmpeg in non-rooted android

Answer (score 6):

JAVE it is very simple to convert media file to another format media. http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're going to strip out the audio from your mp4 file and save it as mp3.  I haven't tried to do anything with audio encodings, but I've used Xuggler ( http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/ ) pretty successfully as a library to access video, and their documentation claims to support audio as well.